# How to integrate WebKit into legacy Motif application

Tags: qt, web-applications, dialog, webkit, motif

We have a large and complex legacy Motif application into which we would like to integrate the WebKit (http://trac.webkit.org/wiki).
I'm not aware of a Motif port of the WebKit (at least didn't find one), but found that it works with Qt, which has even good support for it with the QWebKit (see http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qtwebkit.html).
Qt can be integrated into Motif with the Qt Motif extension (see http://docs.huihoo.com/qt/solutions/4/qtmotifextension/qtmotif-overview.html).

Has anybody already tried this and found it to be a workable solution? Or is there even a better way to archieve this?

Some background why we want to do this:
The application is to be changed step by step into modern technology. A part of it (many dialogs) will turn into a web application (could be JSF or GWT). To have this dialogs still available in the old App, the idea is to use the Webkit to display the ported dialogs directly in the Motif App.

Comment: Even better: port it to Qt. It should be a much smaller impedance mismatch to your existing code. A whole big lot of legacy Motif code was ported to Qt step-by-step over the years.